# How to set, endIconMode in TextInputLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android

**Problem:**
I'm working on a project, and I need to set the `endIconMode`  programmatically but I'm not getting it, I always get one  `NullPointerException`. In XML, it works perfectly, but in that case I need to do it programmatically.

**Console**

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.stackteste, PID: 5167
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.input.TextInputLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class 
         android.input.TextInputLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at .stackteste.fragment.inputs.Inpu1Fragment.onCreateView(Inpu1Fragment.java:30)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    E/AndroidRuntime:at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
            at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.FrameLayout.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
            at android.input.TextInputLayout.isEndIconVisible(TextInputLayout.java:3036)
            at android.input.TextInputLayout.setEndIconVisible(TextInputLayout.java:3022)
            at android.input.TextInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.java:2966)
            at android.input.TextInputLayout.initializeInputContainer(TextInputLayout.java:861)
            at android.input.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:457)
            at android.input.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:432)
```

**What i tried:**

```
    private void initializeInputContainer() {
        Types inputTypes = new Types(this.type, mContext);
    
        this.setHint(inputTypes.stylesHint.get("hint"));
        this.setHintTextColor((ColorStateList.valueOf(inputTypes.styles.get("hintTextColor"))));
        this.setDefaultHintTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(inputTypes.styles.get("defaultHintTextColor")));
        this.setBoxStrokeColor(inputTypes.styles.get("boxStrokeColor"));
        this.setBoxBackgroundMode(BOX_BACKGROUND_OUTLINE);
        this.setBoxBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        this.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE); // Line 861
        isEndIconVisible();
    
      }
```

**XML**

```
    <input.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:typeInput="password">
    
        <input.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
    </input.TextInputLayout>
```

**custom attribute:**

```
  private void initAttributesArray(TypedArray attrsArray) {

    type = attrsArray.getString(R.styleable.TextInputLayout_typeInput);

  }
```

**Class that configures some attributes**

```
public class Types {

private Context context;
public HashMap<String, Integer> styles = new HashMap<>();
public HashMap<String, Drawable> stylesIcon = new HashMap<>();
public HashMap<String, CharSequence> stylesHint = new HashMap<>();

public Types(String type, Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    switch (type) {
        case "text":
            styles = inputTextStyles();
            stylesHint = inputTextStylesHint();
            break;
        case "password":
            styles = inputPasswordStyles();
            stylesHint = inputPasswordStylesHint();
            break;
        case "search":
            styles = inputSearchStyles();
            stylesHint = inputSearchStylesHint();
            break;
        case "action":
            styles = inputActionStyles();
            break;
        case "textarea":
            styles = inputTextareaStyles();
            stylesHint = inputTextareaStylesHint();
            break;
        case "select":
            styles = inputSelectStyles();
            stylesHint = inputSelectStylesHint();
            break;

    }
}

// Styles hashmap will receive all typeStyles already populated (by button type)
HashMap<String, Integer> typeStyles = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, CharSequence> typeStylesHint = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Drawable> typeStylesIcons = new HashMap<>();

public HashMap<String, Integer> inputTextStyles() {
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("hintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_dark));
    typeStyles.put("defaultHintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeWidthPx", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_width_thin));
    typeStyles.put("boxCornerRadiiResources", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_radius_XS));
    return typeStyles;
}

//Set hint in input of type TEXT
public HashMap<String, CharSequence> inputTextStylesHint() {
    typeStylesHint.put("hint", "Texto");

    return typeStylesHint;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> inputPasswordStyles() {
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("hintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_dark));
    typeStyles.put("defaultHintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeWidthPx", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_width_thin));
    typeStyles.put("boxCornerRadiiResources", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_radius_XS));

    return typeStyles;
}

//Set hint in input of type PASSWORD
public HashMap<String, CharSequence> inputPasswordStylesHint() {
    typeStylesHint.put("hint", "Senha");

    return typeStylesHint;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> inputSearchStyles() {
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("hintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_dark));
    typeStyles.put("defaultHintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeWidthPx", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_width_thin));
    typeStyles.put("boxCornerRadiiResources", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_radius_XS));

    return typeStyles;
}

//Set hint in input of type SEARCH
public HashMap<String, CharSequence> inputSearchStylesHint() {
    typeStylesHint.put("hint", "Search");

    return typeStylesHint;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> inputActionStyles() {
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));


    return typeStyles;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> inputTextareaStyles() {
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("hintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_dark));
    typeStyles.put("defaultHintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeWidthPx", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_width_thin));
    typeStyles.put("boxCornerRadiiResources", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_radius_XS));

    return typeStyles;
}

//Set hint in input of type TEXTAREA
public HashMap<String, CharSequence> inputTextareaStylesHint() {
    typeStylesHint.put("hint", "Textarea");

    return typeStylesHint;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> inputSelectStyles() {
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("hintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_dark));
    typeStyles.put("defaultHintTextColor", context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_neutral_darkest));
    typeStyles.put("boxStrokeWidthPx", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_width_thin));
    typeStyles.put("boxCornerRadiiResources", (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.border_radius_XS));

    return typeStyles;
}

//Set hint in input of type SELECT
public HashMap<String, CharSequence> inputSelectStylesHint() {
    typeStylesHint.put("hint", "Selecione");

    return typeStylesHint;
}
}
```

**I looked for a way to make this work in several places, and I didn't find it, so the stackoverflow was suggested.
Thank you all!**

Comment: Post only your code. It is not clear how you create the TIL (programmatically o with a layout). The method setEndIconMode is not the problem.

Comment: I will edit my question, thanks!

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti updated question.